# Sampling in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am sampling points in each image using the following function. tf.range gives an error if batch_size is None. How do I sample in tensorflow

```
def sampling(binary_selection,num_points, points):
  """
      binary_selection: tensor of size (batch_size, points) 
          with values 1.0 or 0.0. Indicating positive and negative points. 
          We want to sample num_points from positive points of each image
      points: tensor of size (batch_size, num_points_in_image)
      num_points: number of points to sample for each image
  """
  batch_size = points.get_shape()[0]
  indices = tf.multinomial((tf.log(binary_selection)), num_points)
  indices = tf.cast(tf.expand_dims(indices, axis=2), tf.int32)
  batch_seq = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(batch_size), axis=1) 
  im_indices = tf.expand_dims(tf.tile(batch_seq, [1, num_points]), axis=2) 
  indices = tf.concat([im_indices, indices], axis=2)
  return tf.gather_nd(points, indices)
```

I get the following error

```
_dimension_tensor_conversion_function raise ValueError("Cannot convert an unknown Dimension to a Tensor: %s" % d) ValueError: Cannot convert an unknown Dimension to a Tensor: ?
```

During the test and training time I will have batch_size an integer but when I initialize I want to give None as input so that batch size can be varied during test and training time.

Comment: how is  batch_size obtained?. use tf.shape() to get it.

Comment: I am trying to understand your problem. The `sampling` function takes three inputs.  Please clarify these three inputs. I am also writing my understanding here based on your code:

Comment: `binary_selection:` The shape is (None * class_labels). It is representing the exponential logits. `None` is corresponing to batch size.

Comment: `num_points:` The shape is an integer. Representing how many classses you are sampling from each logits

Comment: `points:` The shape is (None * class_labels). Please let me know if my understanding is correct.

Comment: I added more content to the description. Does it now clarify all your doubts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a value to `batch_size`.

It needs to be initialized.

Currently, it is not given any value.